# How to improve code performance without using more number of try catch in java

Tags: java, xml, json, performance, try-catch

I have a following code where i use to read a message from third party i will convert it from xml to json in message sometimes i may not have all the values depends on the scenerios the values count will be change so sometimes i missing some values in the middle and  stop printing them if i use try catch for every value i am getting with out missing any value(Null values) .  My question is instead of using try catch for each and every line is there any other option.

```
try{
            printmsg.setGatepass(tosPrint.get("gatepass").toString());
            } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            LogWriter.LogErrorMessage(e);
        }try{
            printmsg.setTransactionType(tosPrint.get("transactionType").toString());
            } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            LogWriter.LogErrorMessage(e);
        }try{
            printmsg.setContainer(tosPrint.get("container").toString());
            } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            LogWriter.LogErrorMessage(e);
        }try{
            printmsg.setSsco(tosPrint.get("ssco").toString());
            } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            LogWriter.LogErrorMessage(e);
        }try{
            printmsg.setWgt(tosPrint.get("wgt").toString());
            } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            LogWriter.LogErrorMessage(e);
        }try{
            printmsg.setTruckingcmpny(tosPrint.get("truckingCompany").toString());
            } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            LogWriter.LogErrorMessage(e);
        }try{
            printmsg.setIssuetime(tosPrint.get("issueTime").toString());
            } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            LogWriter.LogErrorMessage(e);
        }try{
            printmsg.setLicense(tosPrint.get("driverLicense").toString());
            } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            LogWriter.LogErrorMessage(e);
        }try{
            printmsg.setChasis(tosPrint.get("chasis").toString());
            } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            LogWriter.LogErrorMessage(e);
        }try{
            descNodes = tosPrint.getJSONObject("description");
            linelist = descNodes.getJSONArray("eachLine");
            printmsg.setDescription_lines(new String[linelist.length()]);
            for (int i=0;i<linelist.length(); i++)
            {
                printmsg.getDescription_lines()[i]=  linelist.getString(i);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            LogWriter.LogErrorMessage(e);
        }
```

suppose if i have the values of gatepass,transactionType,container,ssco,driverLicense,chasis and missing some values like wgt,issueTime,truckingCompany i am able to print up to ssco if with out using try catch and using with try catch i am able to print all the values so is there any option with out using number of try catch block how to acheive printing all the values if any values are missing i.e., null.

Comment: Use a library like GSON. And don't use an anti-pattern like the above; it makes my eyes bleed and is going to be incredibly slow.

Comment: exception handling is for exceptions, not for normal control flow.

Comment: Submit this to [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com). Be warned though, people over there don't take kindly to duplicated logic and exception abuse.

Comment: How to convert xml to json using GSON in java

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I could suggest is to override/modify .get() method of "tosPrint". You must handle exception in this method it self. If you like this approach please show more code behind and after of what you shared above.
See below code sample for help:

Create a class variable tosPrint.
Create a private get method in your class.
You must tryout in this way as code given below. I don't have a JVM installed on my machine right now. Please cooperate with compilation errors.

```
public class PrintingMsgs{

    private TosPrint tosPrint;

      /*Here you wrap the get() method of third party jar */
    private String get(String str){
                   try{
                          return tosPrint.get(str).toString();
                   } catch (JSONException e) {
                          e.printStackTrace();
                          LogWriter.LogErrorMessage(e);
                   }
                   return null;
      }


    mainMethod(){
        tosPrint = new TosPrint();
        Printmsg printmsg= new Printmsg();

        printmsg.setGatepass(get("gatepass"));
        printmsg.setTransactionType(get("transactionType"));
        printmsg.setContainer(get("container"));
        printmsg.setSsco(get("ssco"));
        printmsg.setWgt(get("wgt"));
        printmsg.setTruckingcmpny(get("truckingCompany"));
        printmsg.setIssuetime(get("issueTime"));
        printmsg.setLicense(get("driverLicense"));
        printmsg.setChasis(get("chasis"));

        try{
                    descNodes = tosPrint.getJSONObject("description");
                    linelist = descNodes.getJSONArray("eachLine");
                        printmsg.setDescription_lines(new String[linelist.length()]);
                        for (int i=0;i<linelist.length(); i++)
                        {
                         printmsg.getDescription_lines()[i]=  linelist.getString(i);
                        }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                        LogWriter.LogErrorMessage(e);
             }
    }
}
```

Comment: Here i am using third party jar file java-json.jar to convert this xml to json so i am not authorized to modify the super class i just use them.

Comment: That's Ok. Write a wrapper class as I wrote above in sample code. Are you still confused to write the above logic in java? If so, please share the full class file.

Comment: Here tosPrint is a POJO Class

Comment: I have added the full implementation of java file. Hope this is a easy to understand for you.

Comment: public class PrintJobMsgStructure {

 String bkbl = "";
 String bkcnt = "";
 public JSONObject jsonObject=null;

  private String getString(String str){
         try{
                return jsonObject.getString(str).toString();
         } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
         }
         return null;
      }

 public PrintJobMsgStructure()
 {
 }

 public String getBkbl() {
  return bkbl;
 }

 public void setBkbl(String bkbl) {
  this.bkbl = bkbl;
 }

 public String getBkcnt() {
  return bkcnt;
 }

 public void setBkcnt(String bkcnt) {
  this.bkcnt = bkcnt;
 }}

Comment: I am trying as you said but it is not working it is not entering into the wrapper method

Comment: How did you initialize jsonObject. Can you share the code where you are using jsonObject. Basically you have to initiate it as below:


PrintJobMsgStructure p= new PrintJobMsgStructure();
p.jsonObject = new JsonObject();

else you have to make it private member and use getter and setter.

Comment: PrintJobMsgStructure msg=new PrintJobMsgStructure();msg.setBkbl("YES");msg.setBkcnt("25");
String xml1="<licenseplate>"+ "<unformatted>ADER</unformatted>"+ "<formatted>ABC123</formatted>" "<nationality>FIN</nationality>"+ "<confidence>1.1</confidence>"+ "</licenseplate>";
JSONObject json=new JSONObject();
JSONObject tosPrint = null;
try {tosPrint = XML.toJSONObject(xml1);

Comment: } catch (JSONException e) {
}JSONObject licenseplate;
try {licenseplate = tosPrint.getJSONObject("licenseplate");
String formatted=licenseplate.getString("formatted");
String nationality=licenseplate.getString("nationality");
String unformattedTest=msg.jsonObject.getString("unformatted");}

Comment: i am using jsonObject as above please suggest me to move forward

Comment: Thank you so much i was implemented as you said i got what i need .

Comment: May I request you to update your question with the solution you implemented. Thanks

Comment: private static String get(JSONObject jsonObj,String str){
JSONObject localJson=jsonObj;
try{
return localJson.get(str).toString();
}catch(Exception je){
je.printStackTrace();
}return localJson.toString();
}public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
String xml1=
"<licenseplate>"
+ "<unformatted>ADER</unformatted>"
+ "<formatted>ABC123</formatted>"
+ "<nationality>FIN</nationality>"
+ "<confidence>1.1</confidence>"
+ "<date>"
+ "<year>2012</year>"
+ "<month>6</month>"
+ "<day>21</day>"
+ "<hour>11</hour>"+ "<minute>18</minute>"+ "<second>29</second>"+ "</date>"+ "</licenseplate>";

Comment: can you please add the code in above question as an update so that we can read.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use one try-catch block for all yours logic. If one of these steps will be have a exception - next step will not be executed:

```
    try{
        printmsg.setGatepass(tosPrint.get("gatepass").toString());
        printmsg.setTransactionType(tosPrint.get("transactionType").toString());
        printmsg.setContainer(tosPrint.get("container").toString());
        printmsg.setSsco(tosPrint.get("ssco").toString());
        printmsg.setWgt(tosPrint.get("wgt").toString());
        printmsg.setTruckingcmpny(tosPrint.get("truckingCompany").toString());
        printmsg.setIssuetime(tosPrint.get("issueTime").toString());
        printmsg.setLicense(tosPrint.get("driverLicense").toString());
        printmsg.setChasis(tosPrint.get("chasis").toString());
        descNodes = tosPrint.getJSONObject("description");
        linelist = descNodes.getJSONArray("eachLine");
        printmsg.setDescription_lines(new String[linelist.length()]);
        for (int i=0;i<linelist.length(); i++)
        {
            printmsg.getDescription_lines()[i]=  linelist.getString(i);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        LogWriter.LogErrorMessage(e);
    }
```

Comment: The above code which you mentioned is already i have tried suppose if am having first and last value middle value is null then it is catching exception and i am not able to print the last value so is there any other approach to continue

Comment: public class JsonTestDemo {

 public static JSONObject jsonObject=null;
 private static JSONObject getJSONObject(String str){
   try{
    System.out.println("inside of try");
             return jsonObject.getJSONObject(str);
      } catch (JSONException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
      }
  System.out.println("below catch");
   return jsonObject;
 }

  private static String getString(JSONObject lic,String str){
   JSONObject innerObject=lic;
        try{
return innerObject.getString(str).toString();
} catch (JSONException e) {
e.printStackTrace();}return innerObject.toString();}

Answer (score 0):

Have you  tried xstream customization, writing convertors. ?

Comment: Sorry No idea about it